# Is there a way to update to OpenSSH 5.9 from OpenSSH_5.6p1 on a MAC?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, macports, openssh

There are certain security holes that are apparently filled in OpenSSH 5.9. I tried downloading the openssh-5.9.tar.gz file from the openssh website, but i have no idea how to use the source code to update the version on my mac(10.7.3). Is this doable or is it something that apple will need to update when releasing the next version of lion?

```
  ssh -v
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install macports, a system for installing and upgrading software packages on OSX ([http://www.macports.org](http://www.macports.org/install.php)).
Then just "`sudo port install openssh`"

The ports openssh will be installed in `/opt/local/bin`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively use [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead.

After [installing](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) homebrew you run:

```
brew install openssh
```

Note the numbers:

- MacPorts 16141 packages (impressive!)
- Homebrew 2207 packages

However, homebrew specifically avoids listing things that should be loaded by other tools, (eg. npm, gems, python eggs, etc.)

It's worth your while looking at both. MacPorts uses a separate `/opt/local` as it's root as Samuel indicates, while brew will use `/usr/local` homebrew also avoids using sudo, unlike MacPorts.

Homebrew, while having less packages available, it still my packager of choice, early experiences of it are not so nice, but at this point, it's mature and stable, bear the dates in mind when you do your research. (blog posts etc.)